# Why isn't overflow hidden working when the display is too small to fit the prefixed emoji?

Tags: css

Why doesn't this overflowed bus icon hide with:

```
.buses li:before {
  content: "\1F68C";
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
}

a {
  font-size: 110%;
}

strong {
  font-size: 180%;
}

ul,
ol {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.buses li:before {
  content: "\1F68C";
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#stations li:before {
  content: "";
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.buses {
  display: table;
}

.buses li {
  display: table-row;
}

.buses time {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 3em;
}

#stations li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.busstopid {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 5em;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input#id {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://newcss.net/lite.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="buses">

  <li>
    <strong>
    <a href="https://busrouter.sg/#/services/26">26</a>
    </strong>

    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:37:53+08:00">-5m</time>
    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:48:46+08:00">5m</time>
    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:56:26+08:00">13m</time>

  </li>

  <li>
    <strong>
    <a href="https://busrouter.sg/#/services/67">67</a>
    </strong>

    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:38:40+08:00">-4m</time>
    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:43:53+08:00">50s</time>
    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:47:57+08:00">4m</time>

  </li>

  <li>
    <strong>
    <a href="https://busrouter.sg/#/services/2">2</a>
    </strong>

    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:38:58+08:00">-4m</time>
    <time datetime="2022-05-09T15:59:37+08:00">16m</time>
    <time datetime="2022-05-09T16:10:26+08:00">27m</time>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: The bus icon doesn't overflow the `:before` as the `:before` doesn't even have a fixed width. Additionally, it is an `inline` element.

Comment: How do I address this problem then? Setting width & display?

Comment: I'd just hide the icon with a media query if the screen is too narrow.

Comment: What do you want it to look like if the screen isn't wide enough to fit it all in? You could for example cut down the padding on narrower viewports and/or reduce the font size if you want it all still to show.